# Unable to make my style-sheets or images work in my bootstrap to wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have started **bootstrap** to wordpress developement, first built the bootstrap site, next used the underscores, now changing the header.php file
copied all my assets to root folder of the theme folder(/var/www/html/b2w/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/),
my header files bootstrap link is as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

it doesn't work. If i click on the link in view source page it says you have no permission to acess this directory. Is this fault of my server setting or just the code.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to load CSS/JS into wordpress. The "proper" ways are fully described here. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402 If you are going to be doing a lot of Wordpress development, definitely learn to register/enqueue them properly.

Comment: Hey that's very informational thanks for the suggestion, I am a python programmer, trying out WordPress, the process for WordPress-ifying the website is pretty long. Thank you for showing me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use this may help you

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was with the assets directory I copy pasted it from the desktop, lamp needs all its folders to have 0777 permissions but as the assets was from my desktop it was having 0775 permissions, so I just did

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/
```

In the html directory all went to normalnormal, that was the reason why I was getting the you don't have permission to view this file error when I clicked on CSS sheet link. Than you all appreciate your help.